# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction with net/http

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl, net-http

I want to use the GetInfoByZIP servide of this WSDL http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL using net/http but always get the error "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction"

```
path = '/uszip.asmx'
#http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL
# Create the SOAP Envelope
data = <<-EOF
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
 <GetInfoByZIPResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
  <GetInfoByZIPResult>
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Table>
        <CITY>Beverly Hills</CITY>
        <STATE>CA</STATE>
        <ZIP>90210</ZIP>
        <AREA_CODE>310</AREA_CODE>
        <TIME_ZONE>P</TIME_ZONE>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </GetInfoByZIPResult>
</GetInfoByZIPResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>EOF


host = "www.webservicex.net"
http = Net::HTTP.new(host)
resp = http.post(path, data, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction' => 'GetInfoByZIP' })
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The soapAction seems incorrect.

Try using the complete soapAction as specified in the example here:

http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?op=GetInfoByZIP

```
POST /uszip.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByZIP"

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetInfoByZIP xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
          <USZip>string</USZip>
        </GetInfoByZIP>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Change your code as follows:

```
resp = http.post(path, data, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction' => 'http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetInfoByZIP' })
```

Comment: Perfect!! Works!! Thanks